Facebook Oembed Read Can't Request Advanced Access
I have a Facebook app with business verification completed. My app is a consumer app and has standard access to oEmbed read. My goal is to use the oEmbed Read feature. However, when I test its endpoints using the Graph API Explorer or Postman, I receive the following error:

(#10) To use 'oEmbed Read', your use of this endpoint must be reviewed
and approved by Facebook. To submit this 'oEmbed Read' feature for
review, please read our documentation on reviewable features:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review.

I used app id | client id as access token. Exp: 12346|879565654
I can't request advanced access of oEmbed Read because the button is disabled. For enable it I need to use the api and get 200, but it gets the error I provided above. I'm stuck because of this. Is someone know what should I do and give me steps? Or is this just a Facebook bug?

I tried sending request with Postman, with SDK and with Graph API explorer while app is in live mode and dev mode, but I still get the error provided above.
